# Listening on a port on a multihomed machine

Tags: sockets, tcp

Imagine a situation: a machine has two IP addresses, 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2. Program A creates a socket, binds it to 10.0.0.1, TCP port 1000, and listens.

Then program B creates a socket, binds it to 0.0.0.0, port 1000, and listens.

What would happen? Will program B quietly be bound to 10.0.0.2 only? Will the second listen call error out? More importantly, is that a defined scenario or an implementation detail?

Comment: In my experience program B will get quietly bound only to 10.0.0.2, but I don't know where that's documented.   (it'll say it's bound to `*`, but it won't receive connections destined for 10.0.0.1)

Comment: I performed some tests on macOS - the `bind` calls to the two addresses don't interfere, and the `bind` to `0.0.0.0` does get _obscured_ by the `bind` to the other more specific address (regardless of which order they're done), such that when that first port disappears the second program B can then receive connections on the first address.

Comment: On Windows Server 2003 and later, the behavior is the same as Alnitak describes. However, on Windows XP and earlier, the second `bind` would fail with a `WSAEADDRINUSE` error instead. This behavior is described in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621.aspx).